# Test multiple http requests to express application using Jasmine

Tags: express, jasmine

I have installed Jasmine CLI globally using `npm install -g jasmine`

I'm trying to test multiple http requests at once using test suite below, multiple calls per each requests were sent (seeing output of `console.log()` but nothing returned so the test was failure, please guide me is this possible to do so ? and how to do this ?

*index.js*

```
var app = require('express')();
var request = require('request');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('GET /');
    res.status(200);
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

*spec/multipleRequestSpec.js*

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

describe('express application', function() {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var statusCode = [0, 0];
    var b = ['', ''];

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        async.parallel([
            function() {
                request.get(baseUrl, function(err, res, body) {
                    statusCode[0] = res.statusCode;
                    b[0] = body;
                })
            }
            ,
            function() {
                request.post(baseUrl, function(err, res, body) {
                    statusCode[1] = res.statusCode;
                    b[1] = body;
                })
            }
        ], done());
    });

    it('should return 200', function() {
        expect(statusCode[0]).toBe(200);
    });

    it('should return hello world', function() {
        expect(b[0]).toEqual('Hello World');
    });

    it('should return error 404', function() {
        expect(statusCode[1]).toBe(404);
    });
});
```

#### Edited

When testing only one request I place `done()` inside the `request()` it works just fine, but I quite confuse where to place `done()` when using `async.pararell()`

*spec/requestSpec.js*

```
var request = require('request');

describe('expresss application', function() {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
    var statusCode = 0;

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        request.get(baseUrl, function(err, res, body) {
            statusCode = res.statusCode;
            done();
        });

    });

    it('should return 200', function() {
        expect(statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `describe` block you initiate variable `body`. And you use it in `it` blocks. But in request.get and in request.post you have callback function with parameter `body` which is in use instead of your  `describe` `body` variable.

Change ***beforeEach*** to:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            request.get(baseUrl, function(err, res, reqBody) {
                statusCode[0] = res.statusCode;
                body[0] = reqBody;
                callback();
            })
        }
        ,
        function(callback) {
            request.post(baseUrl, function(err, res, reqBody) {
                statusCode[1] = res.statusCode;
                body[1] = reqBody;
                callback();
            })
        }
    ], done);
});
```

I think that you should also check `err` param in request callbacks. Because there may be errors which fails/pass your tests.

For api endpoints tests it is more easy to use [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest) instead of `request`.

Comment: thanks @Krzysztof I tried it but still not working, I think the problem is about where to place the `done()` callback

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check it again (what i write before also was correct, but now I resolves one more problem)

Comment: Your answer actually solves my problem thanks, but I doubt why if I have more than one of `it()` block the request will be sent by the number of `it()` blocks